# Python - NameError when import class module

Tags: python, class, import, nameerror

I am getting the following error when I run my script:
*NameError: name 'curr_period_2' is not defined*

I have not used Classes much, and this is the first time I have had them in a seperate module.

What I am trying to do is just change one object attribute with the change_object function.

Don't consider what the code does, as this is just a little test.

Any help is much appreciated.

MyClass.py

```
class MyPeriod:

def __init__(self, year, month):
    self._year = year
    self._month = month

@property
def year(self):
    return self._year


@year.setter
def year(self, year):
    self._year = year
```

MyMain.py

```
    from MyClass import MyPeriod

    def main():
        curr_period = MyPeriod(2028, 1)
        print(f'Object 1 is {curr_period.year}-{curr_period._month}')
        curr_period.year = curr_period.year + 1
        print(f'Object 1 +1  is {curr_period.year}-{curr_period._month}')

    def init_object():
        curr_period_2 = MyPeriod(2038, 1)
        print((f'Object 2 is {curr_period_2.year}-{curr_period_2._month}'))

    def change_object():
        curr_period_2.year = curr_period_2.year * 2
        print(f'Object " * 2' is {curr_period_2.year}-{curr_period_2._month})

    init_object()
    change_object()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: You have an error in `change_object` function. You do not initialize `curr_period_2` but start using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`curr_period_2` does not exist in `change_object` since it is a local variable for `init_object` function. You could try passing it as a param to `change_object` function:

```
def init_object():
    curr_period_2 = MyPeriod(2038, 1)
    print((f'Object 2 is {curr_period_2.year}-{curr_period_2._month}'))
    return curr_period_2

def change_object(current_period_2):
    curr_period_2.year = curr_period_2.year * 2
    print(f'Object " * 2' is {curr_period_2.year}-{curr_period_2._month})
```

then:

```
period = init_object()
change_object(current_period_2=period)
```

Or try using [global](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python) variable

Answer (score 0):

main(), init_object() and change_object() are "alone/local/independent" functions,  so variables inside than are local only (not global).

I thing the best way to solve this, is declaring those internal variables as Global, inside those functions.

see:

```
from MyClass import MyPeriod

def main():
    # first of all declare curr_period as global
    global curr_period

    curr_period = MyPeriod(2028, 1)
    print(f'Object 1 is {curr_period.year}-{curr_period._month}')
    curr_period.year = curr_period.year + 1
    print(f'Object 1 +1  is {curr_period.year}-{curr_period._month}')

def init_object():
    #same here "Global" declaration
    global curr_period_2

    curr_period_2 = MyPeriod(2038, 1)
    print((f'Object 2 is {curr_period_2.year}-{curr_period_2._month}'))

def change_object():
    curr_period_2.year = curr_period_2.year * 2
    print(f'Object " * 2' is {curr_period_2.year}-{curr_period_2._month})

init_object()
change_object()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```